# iterate over a large number of entities on appengine with go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

On app engine I have a large number of entities of a particular kind.
I want to run a function on each entity (e.g. edit the entity or copy it)
I would do this in a taskqueue but a taskqueue is limited to 10 minutes runtime and each function call is prone to many kinds of errors. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution although I'm hoping someone out there has a better solution. I also wonder if this is prone to fork bombs e.g. if the task runs twice, it will set off two chains of iteration.. ! I'm only using it to iterate a few hundred thousand entities, although the operation on each entity is expensive.

First I create a taskqueue for running each individual function call on an entity one at a time:

```
queue:
- name: entity-iter
  rate: 100/s
  max_concurrent_requests: 1
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 3
    task_age_limit: 30m
    min_backoff_seconds: 200
```

and then I have an iterate entity method which, given the kind, will call your delay func on each entity with the key.

```
package sysadmin

import (
    "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/log"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/delay"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/taskqueue"
)


func ForEachEntity(kind string, f *delay.Function) *delay.Function {
    var callWithNextKey *delay.Function // func(c context.Context, depth int, cursorString string) error
    callWithNextKey = delay.Func("something", func(c context.Context, depth int, cursorString string) error {
        q := datastore.NewQuery(kind).KeysOnly()
        if cursorString != "" {
            if curs, err := datastore.DecodeCursor(cursorString); err != nil {
                log.Errorf(c, "error decoding cursor %v", err)
                return err
            } else {
                q = q.Start(curs)
            }
        }
        it := q.Run(c)
        if key, err := it.Next(nil); err != nil {
            if err == datastore.Done {
                log.Infof(c, "Done %v", err)
                return nil
            }
            log.Errorf(c, "datastore error %v", err)
            return err
        } else {
            curs, _ := it.Cursor()
            if t, err := f.Task(key); err != nil {
                return err
            } else if _, err = taskqueue.Add(c, t, "entity-iter"); err != nil {
                log.Errorf(c, "error %v", err)
                return err
            }
            if depth - 1 > 0 {
                if err := callWithNextKey.Call(c, depth - 1, curs.String()); err != nil {
                    log.Errorf(c, "error2 %v", err)
                    return err
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    })
    return callWithNextKey
}
```

example usage:

```
var DoCopyCourse = delay.Func("something2", CopyCourse)

var DoCopyCourses = ForEachEntity("Course", DoCopyCourse)

func CopyCourses(c context.Context) {
    //sharedmodels.MakeMockCourses(c)
    DoCopyCourses.Call(c, 9999999, "")
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I can set the name of the task to the entity key to stop the risk of tasks being created twice?

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you're re-running the query for every result and creating a task to do something with that result (entity)?  That seems like a lot of queries and tasks.  Could you not just run your job on a task queue and 'paginate' your query results into < 10 minute pages, each time enqueueing a new Task with the cursor to mark the current position?   I guess it depends how much work you're doing on each entity.

Comment: yeah i wasn't too worried about the cost of pulling the next key after the current cursor - or i coulda batched them more - tho then there is more chance of failure within that task - and I wouldn't know which key to restart the task from. callwithnextkey is a task itself. it calls itself but it also calls the other task (copycourse). copy course has to great a bunch of course groups etc so does a fair amount of work.